# Start Postgres in Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql-9.3

I am developing a Windows desktop app that connects to a Postgres database.  When testing connections and environmental variables, I have been just going to Component Services and restarting the Postgres service.  Does that reload pg_env.bat?  What is the command prompt way of restarting the Postgres server and reloading a revised pg_env.bat?  Thank you.

Comment: The same way you stop and start any other Windows service: `net stop postgresql-9.3` and `net start postgresql-9.3`

Comment: With that method am I am able to set/change postgres environmental variables?